# can I grep both compressed files and uncompressed files using the same command

Tags: logging, grep, debian

I am trying to make a script for grepping log files located in /var/log/. I am able to either grep uncompressed logs or compressed logs (as a result of log rotation) but have not been able to do both in one command (i get "Binary file (standard input) matches" when I try to do so), is it even possible to do such a thing? thanks!

Comment: @StevenPenny .gz, so for instance syslog, syslog.1, syslog.2.gz, syslog.3.gz and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing this using a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) function :

```
greplog () {
    cd /var/log
    {
        cat $1 $1.*[0-9]
        zcat $1.*.gz
    } | grep "$2"
}
```

Usage :

```
$ greplog syslog pattern
```

Comment: To be consistent with grep et al, wouldn't it be better to have `greplog pattern syslog` ?

Answer (score 10):

`zgrep` can do it for you, it handles both compressed and uncompressed files. One drawback is that it cannot treat directories recursively. But for your instance, it is fully sufficient and you can filter e.g. syslog as follows:

```
$ zgrep PATTERN /var/log/syslog*
```

Answer (score 3):

`xzgrep` is a one stop shop for commonly compressed files, at least on Ubuntu 16 and macOS 10.12 (installed with xz from **MacPorts**).  From the [man](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xzgrep-1.html) page:
`xzgrep  invokes  grep(1) on files which may be either uncompressed or  compressed  with  xz(1),  lzma(1),  gzip(1),  or bzip2(1)`.

Usage (note -r is not supported):

`$ find . -type f | parallel -j4 'xzgrep -Hn "PATTERN" {}'`